# Give version programatically to a setup/deployment project

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation, versioning, setup-project

I have created a Visual Studio Deployment Project for my application. We are a using subversion to manage version numbers and I've got versionInfo.cs file which contains the version number. I want to give the version number I have in my application (versionInfo.cs) to the Version Property of the setup project. I am not sure how to it... Do I need to create a custom action? Or what's the best way to do that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue.

I've setup Cruise Control build server and added Nant script to change the version in the setup project.

Thanks,
Charith

Answer (score 0):

As for me, setting version is a responsibility of build process. So, you don't need a custom action  - it is a part of installation logic and runs at install time. Instead, teach your build engine to put correct version to your installation package (e.g. read it from VersionInfo.cs and put to vdproj file).